# Invalid index 30, size is 30 Android

Tags: java, arrays

I get this error "Invalid index 30 , size is 30" although i have check condition like this

```
if(index < questionPlay.size()) {
    //Do something
    index++;
}
else {
    //Do something else
}
```

But when *index* increases to a larger value than the array's size, it not else but an exception is thrown. Why is this happening?

Comment: you will have to add more code

Comment: i just print element of array at index

Comment: well you must have some error, and that error is not visible in the above code.  So please enhance your question so that we can help you.

Comment: Are you trying to do anything with questionPlay in your else block (i.e. `questionPlay.get(index)`)?

Comment: i'm solved it ! Sorry because i have another check condition with error :(

Comment: @EddyLee, if you've already solved it, please provide your own answer and accept it.

Comment: @MincongHuang no point, just vote to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If array has 30 elements then last valid index will be 29 because it is 0 based.

your condition could be wrong as you first check if it is < size, then you increse it, and use. It should other way around.

Increse, check, use